# Google Cloud Instances Firewall Unable to Login SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

I logged to my ssh in google cloud Linux Machine by mistake i changed firewall rule and i lost ssh connection. now i am not able login to ssh(22), Is there any way to recover that ?

I know I can take shanpshots of my machine and create new instances using that snapshot. but is there anyway to get again ssh login in same machine or i have to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting to the instance via the serial console: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console. From there you should be able to repair the firewall rules.

Comment: This Serial console output is only to view system,boot, and message logs nothing else you can do it from here.

Comment: Make sure to hit the "Connect to serial port" button in the cloud console, not the "View serial port" button (or use `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port ...`). Then hit Enter so that the login prompt appears. This works using serial port 1 on my debian8 instance anyway; perhaps other distros are different.

Comment: **Note:**  @Rupeshkumar's comment is not correct. The the serial console allows to connect interactively but depending on the operating system it might be required to have set a user's password for logging in beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

pjhsea I tried your steps and it is connecting to serial port but it asks passphrase. I was not sure where I have given this passphrase. If you try to access serial port on **gcloud** console then it always asks for passphrase.

So I tried below steps and I was able to connect to serial port to change firewall setting on my ubuntu VM.

Goto Compute Engine -> VM Instances fro left side menu.

Click on name of the VM you are facing issue connecting using SSH.

It will open VM Instance details page.

On details tab under VM name there will be two dropdown for remote access.

SSH and Connect to serial console.

Click on serial console and select serial port 1(console)

This connect to serial console without any passphrase and I was able to change my    firewall rules using below command.

ufw allow 22

Now you should be able to connect using SSH.